# Julia: Writing a function "paramvalues" that returns a dictionary of parameter values

Tags: dictionary, julia, keyword-argument

I am working on an Economics assignment and need to create a function in Julia that takes keyword arguments and returns them in the form of a dictionary. So far this is my code, but it is not running because there is "no method matching getindex(::Nothing, ::Symbol).

```
function paramvalues(a; Nb = 100, Ns = 100, Minval = 0, Maxval = 200, Mincost = 0, Maxcost = 200)
    d = Dict(:Nb => Nb, :Ns => Ns, :Minval => Minval, :Maxval => Maxval, :Mincost => Mincost, :Maxcost => Maxcost)
    for values in a
        d[values] = get(d, values, 0) 
    end
    d 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably closer to what you want:

```
function paramvalues(a; kwargs...)
    @show kwargs
    dict = collect(kwargs)
    @show dict
    return dict
end
```

The magic here is that `kwargs` (aka Key Word Arguments) with the `...` "SLURP", soaks up all the key word arguments into one variable.

And it is an iterator over an array of pairs.  To convert an iterator into a standard collection like an `Array` or a `Dict`, you can use `collect`.  An iterator over pairs turns into a `Dict`.

Trying it out I get this:

```
paramvalues(123;Nb = 100, Ns = 100, Minval = 0, Maxval = 200, Mincost = 0, Maxcost = 200)
kwargs = Base.Iterators.Pairs(:Nb => 100,:Ns => 100,:Minval => 0,:Maxval => 200,:Mincost => 0,:Maxcost => 200)
dict = Pair{Symbol,Int64}[:Nb => 100, :Ns => 100, :Minval => 0, :Maxval => 200, :Mincost => 0, :Maxcost => 200]
6-element Array{Pair{Symbol,Int64},1}:
      :Nb => 100
      :Ns => 100
  :Minval => 0
  :Maxval => 200
 :Mincost => 0
 :Maxcost => 200
```

I don't know what `a` is supposed to be.

It sounds like your error is coming from calling `get` on a variable storing `Nothing` instead of storing a `Dict`.

Also when walking a dictionary, it returns a tuple pair of `(key, value)`.  So use something like this to walk a dictionary:

```
for (k,v) in my_dict
    @show k,v
end
```

Also don't forget to use the `?` in the julia repl and search some of these things.  Like `?Dict` or `?for` or `?enumerate` or `?@show` or `?collect`.

Comment: If you don't need `a`, you can just put the semicolon without any positional arguments, like: `function paramvalues(; Nb = 100, Ns = 100)` ... note the lack of `a`.

Comment: The `...` operator is actually called "slurp" when it 'soaks up' arguments, and "splat" when it spits them out (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#What-does-the-...-operator-do?) In this context it's "slurping".

Comment: Thanks for the correction @DNF . I updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

`Dict` can directly take the keyword-arguments:

```
julia> f(;kw...) = Dict(kw)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(a=5, b=3)
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 2 entries:
  :a => 5
  :b => 3
```